Just to make an ancient package dependency null safe, I need to `pub get` it, but to `pub get` it, it already needs to be null safe
In pubspec.yaml in the Flutter state management samples, I added publish_to: none and raised the sdk to support null safety.

But now when I try to resolve the dependencies

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  todos_repository_local_storage:
    path: ../todos_repository_local_storage
  todos_app_core:
    path: ../todos_app_core
  key_value_store_flutter:
  key_value_store_web:

I find that one of the dependencies, key_value_store_flutter, doesn't support null safety.
flutter_state_management_samples/inherited_widget $ flutter packages get
Resolving dependencies... 
The current Dart SDK version is 3.5.4.

Because inherited_widget_sample depends on key_value_store_web any which doesn't support null safety, version
  solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

What is the right way to proceed? Just to modify key_value_store_flutter and make it null safe, I need to pub get it, but to pub get it, it already needs to be null safe.

Those are privately maintained.  Long old.  Edit: you can probably reach the author through the github repo.

Yeah, I'm with Randal here: that seems like a pretty outdated resource to work from at this point. Your question will likely be closed as you're asking for a recommendation of an off-site resource, which is off-topic (as links tend to rot). If you are wondering about a how to make a specific example from that site null-safe, it's more likely we can help if you post the actual code for that example (and maybe even what you tried already and where you got stuck).

@FrankvanPuffelen Good idea, but I'm having trouble just getting started. I went ahead and changed the question entirely.

This is still incredibly broad. If key_value_store_flutter doesn't support null safety, you'll need to either update that package (i.e. submit a PR and get a release), or replace it with another package. This also seems interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66629994/how-to-mix-sound-null-safety-and-unsound-null-safety-in-flutter, but also requires patching the key_value_store_flutter code.
